# TreeView Node forecolor not changing when called at certain times?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, mouse

I have a treeview, trvActors.

When I try to change the forecolor of a treenode by clicking on it, it does not seem to work, but the surrounding code works.

```
            ((Actor)_rightClickedNode.Tag).IsDefault = true;
            _rightClickedNode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Weirdly enough, the isDefault value changes, but the node does not change color.  This is occurring on a toolstripmenuitem click, but the same thing is also occurring on a simple right click.

Here is the code for a right click on the         private void trvActors_MouseClick event:

```
  trvActors.SelectedNode = trvActors.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

        if (trvActors.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                _rightClickedNode = trvActors.SelectedNode;

                ((Actor)_rightClickedNode.Tag).IsDefault = true;
                _rightClickedNode.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }
```

Same outcome.  The only time I seem to be able to change the forecolor is when I am initially creating the nodes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you have FullRowSelect set to.. if it is true make it false also maybe  you should put your code in the [NodeMouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick.aspx) or [BeforeSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeselect.aspx) events ?

Hope this helps you out,

Comment: It ended up being FullRowSelect : False and using the TreeView1_MouseUp event.

Thank you soooooo much for putting me on the right track.

Comment: Not a problem I am glad that I was able to quickly provide you a solution.. happy coding..